# Logstash date filter does not handle the month

Tags: logstash

Our object, parsed and all:

```
{
         "message" => "[2014-12-15 14:28:03,786] WARN  org.apache.sshd.serve
        "@version" => "1",
      "@timestamp" => "2014-01-15T14:28:03.786Z",
            "type" => "errorlog",
            "host" => "localhost",
            "path" => "/var/lib/gerrit/log/error_log",
            "tags" => [
    [0] "multiline"
],
"gerrit_timestamp" => "2014-12-15 14:28:03,786",
        "loglevel" => "WARN",
          "object" => "org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSession"
}
```

As you can see we're extracting the date into `gerrit_timestamp` just fine. We then have a date-filter to read `gerrit_timestamp`, and stuff it into `@timestamp`

```
date {
   type => "errorlog"
   match => [ "gerrit_timestamp", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
   target => "@timestamp"
 }
```

so why is @timestamp off by 11 months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience the date function needs to be called with the correct layout for the date, otherwise nothing will come out, I'm not sure why your date is 11 months out in your example, I would recommend you try the following:

```
date {
   type => "errorlog"
   match => [ "gerrit_timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
 }
```

Target in this example is redundant as the default behaviour is to set the value to @timestamp. As per [the date documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) y is year, while Y is year of era, not quite the same, and D is day of year, i.e. between 1-365, not day of month, which is d.